# How can I filter a table based on other table column, considering only a part of the field?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have the following table (named table_1):

```
Column1    Column2    Column3
A          123        'ABCDE'
B          333        'FGHIJ'
C          444        'KLMNO'
```

and I have another table, like this one (named table_2):

```
Column4
'BCD'      
'FGH'
```

Now, I want to filter table_1 using table_2. However, as you can see Column4 doesn't contain the full name of Column3, just part of it. I thought about exporting Column4, putting it in Notes (or any other text app) and doing something like:

```
select * from table_1 where Column3 like '%BCD%' or Column3 like '%FGH%'
```

But I was wondering if there is another way, smarter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `exists` and `like`:

```
select t1.*
from table_1 t1
where exists (
    select 1 from table_2 t2 where t1.column3 like '%' || t2.column4 || '%'
)
```